# Onsen - multiline toolbar

Tags: onsen-ui

Can I have a multi line toolbar?

I need a fixed header for all my pages, but the ons-toolbar have only one line. I need two of it in my header.
It is possible to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put an extra `<div>` with the appearance of a toolbar with `class="navigation-bar"`: http://onsen.io/reference/css.html#toolbar

It is also possible to change the CSS of your current toolbar to make it bigger, if you want. The anwer of this question may be helpful: [Doesn't show div in onsen ui and angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753457/doesnt-show-div-in-onsen-ui-and-angularjs/28757159#28757159)

Hope it helps!

**Edit:** some CSS to do this...

- Fix the position to the top under a main toolbar: `position: fixed; top: 44px;`
- Change the page content so the new toolbar does not overlap with it:

  `ons-toolbar ~ .page__content {
    top: 88px;
  }`

Working here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/YXKyjX

Comment: It is possible to make this second navigation-bar fixed to top like the toolbar?

Comment: I have a problem. I don't know why but if you take the code and open it outside codepen, the second navigation bar change position on my mobile phone and also in FF. It seems that not understand the "position: fixed". Any hint?